# Input's placeholder text disapper on focus and not on typing

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am building a PhoneGap application for Android phones with AngularJS and I have noticed that when I use an old Samsung Galaxy S2 my input's placeholder text disappear on focus but when I use new Samsung Galaxy S4 my input's placeholder text keep on showing until key pressed.

How can i set it so it work the same in all Android phones?

Comment: Use a [polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills)? But is it *really* worth the effort?

Comment: clear text on touch in your java code or do anything else you want to happen when user touches your input placeholder. This way it'll be consistent for every device.

Comment: Is there any quick way to keep the text up there until user enter any key?